# Oracle won't open with certain user id

Tags: c#, oracle, windows-server-2008

I have an application that I run from the task scheduler.   It runs fine if I run it from my account, but not if I run it from a system account (this account has similar permissions as mine on the server (it is even an administrator), but has a non-expiring password.  When I run it from the system account it fails when opening Oracle.  My application does not throw an exception.  It just dies.  However, the event viewer has the following:

```
Application: M921.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.NullReferenceException
Stack:
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.get_Source()
   at M921.Program.Main(System.String[])

Faulting application name: M921.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x58c2d17b
Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x037d2be3
Faulting process id: 0x564
Faulting application start time: 0x01d299ba8cb4ef63
Faulting application path: D:\ScriptingApplications\M921\M921.exe
Faulting module path: unknown
Report Id: cbb37f30-05ad-11e7-97a4-005056824753
```

If I examine the trace logs I find this:

```
<msg time='2017-03-10T10:11:23.998-05:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='clients'
 msg_id='3079483318' type='INCIDENT_ERROR' level='1'
 host_id='PWN401AV1369' host_addr='::1' prob_key='oci 24550 [3221225477]'
 errid='15721' detail_path='C:\Users\scrptadmin\Oracle\oradiag_scrptadmin\diag\clients\user_scrptadmin\host_2384361277_82\trace\ora_3292_1232.trc'>
 <txt>Errors in file



C:\Users\scrptadmin\Oracle\oradiag_scrptadmin\diag\clients\user_scrptadmin\host_2384361277_82\trace\ora_3292_1232.trc  (incident=15721):
oci-24550 [3221225477] [Unhandled exception: Code=c0000005 Flags=0
] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-03-10T10:11:24.186-05:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='clients'
 msg_id='dbgexProcessError:1266:3370026720' type='TRACE' level='16'
 host_id='PWN401AV1369' host_addr='::1'>
 <txt>Incident details in: C:\Users\scrptadmin\Oracle\oradiag_scrptadmin\diag\clients\user_scrptadmin\host_2384361277_82\incident\incdir_15721\ora_3292_1232_i15721.trc
 </txt>
</msg>
```

I have checked all of the permissions that I can think of.  The Database credentials are oracle credentials (not windows credentials;  username and password are part of the connection string)

I am using version 12.1.0 oracle client

I am baffled.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not provided any source code, I am only guessing here. To connect using a privileged account (SYSDBA or SYSOPER), you need to add the DBA privilege attribute to you connection string:

```
//Connect scott/tiger as SYSDBA   
con.ConnectionString = "User Id=scott;Password=tiger;" + 
  "DBA Privilege=SYSDBA;Data Source=oracle;";
```

Oracle documentation [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/featConnecting.htm#ODPNT184)